# What is a better approach to check if a string is subsequence of another string

Tags: string, algorithm

// Approach 1
// Check if s1 is subsequence of s2 (|s1| < |s2|)

```
public static boolean isSubseq1(String s1, String s2) {

  int index = -1;
  for( int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
    
    index = s1.indexOf(s2.charAt(i), index + 1);
    
    if(index == -1)
        return false;
    
  }

  return true;
}
```

// Approach 2
// Check if A is subsequence of B (|B| >= |A|)

```
public static boolean isSubseq2(String B, String A) {

  int j = 0;
  int n = B.length();
  int m = A.length();
  // Traverse str2 and str1, and compare
  // current character of str2 with first
  // unmatched char of str1, if matched
  // then move ahead in str1
  for (int i = 0; i < n && j < m; i++)
     if (A.charAt(j) == B.charAt(i))
         j++;

  // If all characters of str1 were found
  // in str2
  return (j == m);
}
```

Things that I know:

1. In approach 1 we can immediately return false even if one character is not found. But in second approach we traverse all the things even if a character is not found.
2. But in the first approach I have used indexOf(char), will it add to the time complexity or it(indexOf) is done in O(1)?
3. In first approach the bigger string is only traversed once.

PS: The first code is done by me
the second one is from geeksforgeeks

Comment: Maybe [Boyer–Moore–Horspool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm) can help you?

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches have `O(n)` best and worst case time complexity.

In both approaches, the bigger string is traversed only once, because in the first, `s1.indexOf` on itself traverses the string.

Also, your solution also runs in `O(n)` time worst case, as you never check for the same character twice in the big string, smart usage of `index` to avoid checking the no longer interesting prefix makes sure of that<sup>(1)</sup>.

---

(1) assuming the implementation of `indexOf()` is efficient and does not traverse elements before the first index.